# Can't close popup with touch without a specific button in ios

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning now how to create popups in mobile devices, and I created a popup that closes when I touch any part of the screen, but it doesn't work on ios (maybe on all touch devices, haven't checked), only on the computer.

Now based on the information I read here:

[jQuery click events not working in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795944/jquery-click-events-not-working-in-ios)

[Make onclick work on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914568/make-onclick-work-on-iphone)

[How to bind 'touchstart' and 'click' events but not respond to both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018919/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both)

[Cannot close popup() window in iPhone Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766482/cannot-close-popup-window-in-iphone-safari)

The popup opens fine because you press a link attribute `<a>` to open it up, however upon closing I can press any part of the screen.

Here is the code:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal'); // Get the popup
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn"); // Get the button that opens the popup

btn.onclick = function() { // Open the popup 
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

window.onclick = function(event) { // Closes the popup
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I tried adding `cursor: pointer;` in CSS, changing the script in javascript to `onmouseover` instead of `click`, changing the script, changing `window.click` to `div.click` and adding the following code to the javascript script:

```
let touchEvent = 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
window.on(touchEvent, function(event){...});
```

Nothing worked...

I guess I don't quite get how to use the touch event listener, if it's connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add event listeners for touchstart and/or touchend for this to work on mobile devices, check out the snippet below:

```js
// JavaScript
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal'); // Get the popup
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn"); // Get the button that opens the popup

btn.onclick = function() { // Open the popup 
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

let eventsArray = ["click","touchstart", "touchend"];

eventsArray.forEach( function(event) { 
    window.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
      if (e.target === modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    }, false);
});
```

```css
/*CSS*/
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#myModal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#myModal span {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #a600a6;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<body class="overlay">
  <div >
    <button id="myBtn"> 
      Open Modal
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <div id="myModal">
    <span>Hello World!</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Tested on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robert0310/4g5cvx0r/16/) with an iPad and it works.